# Be sure Weakreference is still existing after IsAlive

Tags: c#, weak-references, isalive

If i iterate over a list of `Weakreference`s, how can i be sure, the reference still exists, after proofing via `_ref.IsAlive`?

For example i have this piece of code, where `scopeReferences` is a of `Weakreference`s:

```
foreach (var _ref in scopeReferences)
{
    if (_ref.IsAlive)
    {
        if (_ref.Target is ScriptScope)
        {
            // Is it alive any more?
            ((ScriptScope)_ref.Target).SetVariable(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe some one knows the answer, i just don't want to create any problems due to the fact, i don't know what's going on in this part. Thank you all a lot!

Comment: `IsAlive` is only usable for one thing and that is detecting that it is no longer alive. You have race conditions as you have already gathered for the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

You could copy it to a variable, after which you either have it or you don't, and you can safely test it:

```
foreach (var _ref in scopeReferences)
{
    ScriptScope tmp = _ref.Target as ScriptScope;
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        tmp.SetVariable(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot. That are question written after 10h of work :) I accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: In C# 6 this is a one-liner: `(_ref.Target as ScriptScope)?.SetVariable(name, value)`.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thank you for that hint.